# Subgroup of functions: Show that H is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

## Question: In each of the following, show that H is a subgroup of G.

$G=\langle F(\mathbb{R}),+\rangle$,  H={ f $\in$ F($\mathbb{R}$): f(x)=0 $\text{ for every }$ x $\in$ [0,1]}

I would like someone to just make sure I'm on the right track or if I did it right.

So it the set is not empty.

(i) closure under addition: $f,g \in H$ where $f(x)=0$ and $g(y)=0$. Therefore, $$[f+g](x)=f(x)+g(y)=0+0=0$$
Which means  $f+g \in H$.

(ii) inverse: let $f \in H$ then $f(x)=0$ which means $$(-f)(x)=-f(x)=-0=0$$ so  $-f \in H$.

Comment: Yes and no. You must show that adding two of those functions, gives you a function with the same condition($\forall x \in [0,1], f(x) =0$). Remember to show that.

Comment: A question, is $x\in \{0,1\}$ or $x\in [0,1]$?

Comment: @Miguelgondu x∈[0,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. How come the set is nonempty?, try naming a function that you know is in the set $H$ and obeys $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. (As the tip, I'd recommend using a constant function)
2. For the closure on the addition, you need to prove that given $f,g \in H$, $f+g\in H$. You're very close, but keep in mind that, for $f+g$ to be in $H$, $(f+g)(x) = 0$ for $x\in [0,1]$ must hold. (It is a matter of writing it in a better way)
3. You need to prove that it has a neutral element for $+$, which is the best candidate?
4. Your ideas for the additive inverse are nice enough.
5. There's a better way of checking that $H\leq G$: proving that $H\neq \varnothing$ and that $f,g\in H \rightarrow f-g\in H$ suffices, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure for 1 but y=0? For 2 is it: (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=0+0=0. As for 3: The neutral element should be 0. 5. I'm not understanding, why do I need to check that H is less than G?

Comment: $H \leq G$ is a short way of writing "H is a subgroup of G". The neutral element should be a function. And for 1. you're correct.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, for 2, you should specify that you're taking $x\in [0,1]$. No problem.

Comment: Alright! Thanks again!